# Concurrency problem in updating Jtable/Jframes?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable, jscrollpane

I will try to describe the problem as accurately as possible, since this is a legacy project from someone else that I am trying to fix (to the best of my abilities).I cannot build an accurate working example due to the way this project is done. The way this program was built is wrong in many places so just pinpointing the problem would help me immensely.

There is a Jframe with a menu bar and table. The frame switches between Tables based on which option you click within the menu bar. Here's the problem: When updating the table, the first table seems to be fine, but the other ones fails to update its view properly if something is changed (specifically, it doesn't update upon deletion, but insertion seems fine). This is how the main table is made:

```
public void start(){
 mainTable=new Jtable(model){
  public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
   /* tons of styling here */
  };
}
 /* a bit more styling? */
 renderSecondTable();
 renderThirdTable();

}
```

I apologize for this ugly code, the codebase itself is even worse. Does rendering other tables by calling a method within this "start()" function lead to concurrency problems? Which is why updating the view is problematic? Extra information that might help:

- each table has a seperate Frame, so there is a main frame and then a smaller frame that displays the tables
- buttons for each table (delete, update etc.) are also added in by calling in extra methods like RenderButtonsForTable1()
- They are all AbstractTableModel
- calling FireTableDataChanged() or other similar functions do not seem to do work for non-main-tables
- revalidate and repaint also doesn't work

The table does NOT use removeRow or fireTableRowsDeleted to remove the rows, there are seperate functions that do this with object streams (I don't quite understand this yet). The view seems to update automatically for the main table just fine.

Again I apologize if this is extremely confusing and ugly, the original creator didn't seem to understand what he was doing either :/

Edit: More clarification!

- It seems that it does in fact only have one MAIN frame, and this
  frame swaps out multiple Jpanels (each with a different Table). Within each Panel there is also a scrollpane
- Deleting from the main Panel causes no problems, but deleting entries from other Panels require the Frame to be reopened or else the entry just stays there (also breaks the frame/panel completely if you empty the entire table)
- The entry is properly disposed of in the backend (as far as I can tell)
- any insert/delete is done through an action listener for the corresponding button
- Each table has a seperate Tablemodel (all extends AbstractTableModel) with its seperate functions that all do the same thing
- Table is filled with data read from a database
- all tables are made in the same fashion as the main one above with prepareRenderer

I also drew up a vague diagram of how the Jframe looks:
[image: JframeExample]

Comment: _I cannot build an accurate working example_ I think it is unlikely you get quality help without an [mre]

Comment: Your system should have one and only one `JFrame` and as many `JDialogs` as needed.  The `JDialogs` do not have to be modal.  You should consider creating a new GUI. 
 Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay close attention to the [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) sections.

Comment: 1) All updates to Swing components must be done on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) or you can have concurrency issues. 2) Your application logic should NOT invoke any of the "fireXXX" methods directly. Those methods should only be invoked in the TableModel class.

Comment: @camickr it uses an action listener to invoke the delete method and I have tested it with isEventDispatchThread(). At least the action listener seems to be in the EDT but just doesn't update regardless. The backend seems to function fine and deletes it in the back. So is it safe to say that it is most likely not an EDT issue?

Comment: @c0der I'm desperate. I cannot build a minimal example out of this sadly, not only because it is way too huge to reproduce even on a smaller scale, it is also a problem with privacy (this is technically a project from some company). But thank you for the link!

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc thanks! It seems to follow the only one Jframe rule. But is it ok for a Jframe to "host" multiple different Jpanels? Or could that cause some kind of weird issues?

Comment: "But is it ok for a `JFrame` to "host" multiple different `JPanels`?"  Yes, but the actual answer depends on the specifics.  A `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout`, which means it can hold up to 9 different children `JPanels` at one time.  If you mean several `JPanels` in a sequence, you use one main `JPanel` with a `CardLayout`, and all the other `JPanels` are subordinate to the main `JPanel`.  There's also a `JTabbedPane` when you want the user to choose what to do next.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc thanks! Does something go wrong if there are more than a certain amount of Jpanels within the frame? Or if there are also more things within the Jpanel? While the different Panels never show up at the same time, the frame technically "hosts" a total of 12 different Jpanels depending on what button/menu option that is selected. But only 2-3 Panels show up at once in a frame if that makes sense?

Comment: Assuming this makes sense, the 2 - 3 `JPanels` are the main `JPanels`, and the other `JPanels` are subordinate `JPanels`.  One example would be a `JFrame` with a menu `JPanel`, a viewing `JPanel`, and a status `JPanel`.  The viewing `JPanel` would have a `CardLayout` and host a number of subordinate `JPanels`.  The menu `JPanel` and status `JPanel` would be common across all the subordinate `JPanels`.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc oof maybe that's where it went wrong. Despite all the Jpanels it does not use a Cardlayout, the code seems to just remove and add the panels with an actionlistener. Would that be a possible reason for the panels/tables bugging out?

Comment: Yes, removing and adding `JPanels` is not a good design.  Generally, you create the entire GUI once, in the beginning, and choose what to show to the user at any one time.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc thanks! at least (one of) the underlying problem(s) have been identified now. Since I have to find a way around this for now, are there even other options besides using `revalidate()` and `repaint()` to try and update these panels?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place for an extended discussion.  No, there's no other option.  Rewrite the GUI.